# How to use packer export_opts?

Tags: virtualbox, packer

I build a VirtualBox VM using [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) and I would like to set some VM meta data (e.g. description, version) using the `export_opts` parameter. The [docs](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/virtualbox-iso.html#export_opts) say

> export_opts (array of strings) - Additional options to pass to the VBoxManage export. This can be useful for passing product information to include in the resulting appliance file.

I am trying to do this in a bash script calling packer:

```
desc=' ... some ...'
desc+=' ... multiline ...'
desc+=' ... description ...'
# this is actually done using printf, shortened for clarity
export_opts='[ "version", "0.2.0", "description", "${desc}" ]'

# the assembled string looks OK
echo "export_opts: ${export_opts}"

packer build \
        ... (more options) ...
    -var "export_opts=${export_opts}"             \
        ... (more options) ...
    <packer configuration file>
```

I also tried `--version` instead of `version` and putting `version` and the value into the same string, but none of this works; once exported and re-imported, the VM description is empty.

Does anyone have some working sample code or can help me out with what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you very much.

**Update:**

Following [Anthony Staunton's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38522956), I figured out that adding

```
"export_opts": [ "--vsys", "0", "--version", "0.2.0", "--description", "some test description" ],
```

to the Packer JSON file does work; passing the same string as `--var` to Packer does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem at long last, updated the packer documentation with the example below, [pull](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/pull/3745) [requests](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/pull/3746) pending:

Packer JSON configuration file example:

```json
{
  "type": "virtualbox-ovf",
  "export_opts":
  [
    "--manifest",
    "--vsys", "0",
    "--description", "{{user `vm_description`}}",
    "--version", "{{user `vm_version`}}"
  ],
  "format": "ova",
}
```

A VirtualBox [VM description](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idm3756) may contain arbitrary strings; the GUI interprets HTML formatting. However, the JSON format does not allow arbitrary newlines within a value. Add a multi-line description by preparing the string in the shell before the packer call like this (shell `>` continuation character snipped for easier copy & paste):

```shell
vm_description='some
multiline
description'

vm_version='0.2.0'

packer build \
    -var "vm_description=${vm_description}" \
    -var "vm_version=${vm_version}"         \
    "packer_conf.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify the data as

in your packer json file

```
  "export_opts": [ "--vsys 0 --version \"0.2.0\"", "{{.Name}} --description \"${desc}\" " ],
```

Comment: that works once the syntax is fixed, does not work using a Packer `--var` though; see my update